# why does my nginx return 404 after port forward?

Tags: nginx

I make a port forward(9999 -> 80) from my local computer to my vmware virtual machine.

When I use nginx, 'http//127.0.0.1:9999' will return 404.

When I use apache2, 'http//127.0.0.1:9999' works well.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/wordpress;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    
}
```